# Carrierwave works in development and in heroku local, but not in heroku online deployed

Tags: heroku, amazon-s3, carrierwave

In my Rails app, I'm using `carrierwave-aws` (not `fog`). It works fine for image-uploading in development and in `heroku local`, but when I deploy it, I get this `heroku log`...

```
2016-05-11T09:54:48.072165+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/users" for 110.168.231.136 at 2016-05-11 09:54:48 +0000
2016-05-11T09:54:48.076592+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
2016-05-11T09:54:48.076888+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"fa9b1wD30+tzdF3hxs+sMipSmr/jZLeT/x39S8djQXf9DmfTv/dkhpiIjPiy8ufg//oGdTT+QMvGCRJDtYk08w==", "user"=>{"guest"=>"true", "nickname"=>"", "first_name"=>"Mary", "last_name"=>"Smith", "gender"=>"female", "email"=>"test@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "zip"=>"55544", "face_photo"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x0056329c909d20 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20160511-12-17ng6dj.png>, @original_filename="CEP image13.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[face_photo]\"; filename=\"CEP image13.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">}}
2016-05-11T09:54:48.081994+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms
2016-05-11T09:54:48.333865+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users" host=example.com request_id=6ce23206-cf2c-7705-ae3c-ce39bdb8bd19 fwd="110.168.231.136,110.168.231.136" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4061ms status=500 bytes=1669
2016-05-11T09:54:49.167666+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=example.com request_id=6587b42e-475f-4431-834d-200a2c994126 fwd="110.168.231.136" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=20ms status=301 bytes=802
2016-05-11T09:54:49.159482+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/favicon.ico" for 110.168.231.136 at 2016-05-11 09:54:49 +0000
2016-05-11T09:54:49.876909+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 110.168.231.136 at 2016-05-11 09:54:49 +0000
2016-05-11T09:54:49.884058+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#front as */*
2016-05-11T09:54:49.890819+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/front.html.erb within layouts/application (1.5ms)
2016-05-11T09:54:49.892156+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered shared/_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
2016-05-11T09:54:49.892539+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 8ms (Views: 5.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2016-05-11T09:54:49.905696+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=example.com request_id=54e56ee8-3422-45c3-aa51-34614224d6db fwd="110.168.231.136,110.168.231.136" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=31ms status=200 bytes=1791
```

You'll notice in this log, the `Completed 500 Internal Server Error` -- which I do NOT get when I take out the image uploader (so this is definitely an uploader problem).  BTW, this exact same thing happened to me with `fog`, so that is not the problem.  The error seems to occur at the commencement of my `create` action in Rails 4.

Here is my `config/initializers/carrier_wave.rb`

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.storage    = :aws
  config.aws_bucket = ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET')
  config.aws_acl    = 'public-read'

  config.aws_authenticated_url_expiration = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7

  config.aws_attributes = {
    expires: 1.week.from_now.httpdate,
    cache_control: 'max-age=604800'
  }

  config.aws_credentials = {
    access_key_id:     ENV.fetch('S3_KEY'),
    secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('S3_SECRET'),
    region:            ENV.fetch('S3_REGION') # Required
  }

  config.cache_dir = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"
end
```

As per the advice in https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/how-to%3A-make-carrierwave-work-on-heroku, I added `/tmp/uploads` for `cache_dir`, but to no avail.  And here is my uploader...

```
class FacePhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  process :resize_to_fill => [156, 200]

  storage :aws

  def cache_dir
    "#{Rails .root}/tmp/uploads"
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

end
```

I emphasize that this works fine in the other environments I'd mentioned above.  Only deployed in `Heroku` do I have this `500 Internal Server Error`. I'm perplexed.